# Why Graph API Explorer doesn't return the wall 'feed' based on a user's id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I test the Graph API Explorer from facebook site and write the following parameters:

> https://graph.facebook.com/'userid'/feed?access_token='my access token'

it returns

> {   "data":   [  ] }

I tried it with several group ids and all return the same result.

scope is below

> user_birthday, user_religion_politics, user_relationships, user_relationship_details, user_hometown, user_location, user_likes, user_education_history, user_work_history, user_website, user_managed_groups, user_events, user_photos, user_videos, user_friends, user_about_me, user_status, user_games_activity, user_tagged_places, user_posts, read_page_mailboxes, rsvp_event, email, ads_management, ads_read, read_insights, manage_pages, publish_pages, pages_show_list, pages_manage_cta, pages_manage_leads, publish_actions, read_audience_network_insights, read_custom_friendlists, user_actions.video, user_actions.books, user_actions.music, user_actions.news, user_actions.fitness, public_profile

when I tried it from facebook graph api explorer I found out that its not returning any results. Please I would really appreciate the your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell me that you are accessing others id by the same token or you are taking a different token??

Because if you are using graph explorer then it will give the token for your ID only. And you can see all the feed of your page using

```
me/feed?fields=id,posts,from or 
your_id/feed?fields=id,posts,from
```

Use GET request while using submit button.

Comment: If I use my app, can I get the feed of others

"others_id/feed?fields=id,posts"

Comment: Yes , if you are using your app and your app is approved then you can have feed after having access token from the user.

Comment: Welcome anytime and hit +1 also if you like it!! :)